# Как получить содержимое тега из html-кода

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup

Я использую BeautifulSoup, чтобы получить необходимую информацию из тега div, в котором содержится 10 необходимых тегов ('div', class_="feed-w")

```
response = requests.get('(какая-то ссылка)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
meta = soup.find_all('div', class_="group_feed")
```

Но, когда я прокручиваю страницу вниз, то html-код обновляется, и появляется еще несколько тегов div.

Как получать информацию, пока, например, счетчик необходимых тегов не достигнет какого-либо значения?

Comment: Если данные появляются на странице динамически, то, вероятнее всего, они приходят дополнительным запросом. Нужно изучать сами запросы.

Comment: `pip install requests-html` https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/